# Pygame Shooting Bullets

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Recently ive been trying to create a small game using Pygame, Ive managed to display an image which can move side to side, the trouble ive been having is enabling it to fire bullets using the space bar.

Heres my code so far:
http://pastebin.com/24xDYwY7

Ive now got the bullet to display however it doesnt come out from the "turret.png", and just sits in the top left of the screen.

Is anyone able to help me with this? I am extremely new to python and would appreciate the help

Comment: What problem in particular are you having? Do they not appear, do they not move, are you seeing an error…?

Comment: @Stick The bullet only displays and is stationary in the top left of the screen

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using a technique I like employing in PyGame - using different sprite Groups for separating good guys, bad guys, bullets, blocks, etc… with a single unified 'all the things' Group.

What I don't see is the `all_sprites.update()` call that makes the whole thing work, though I do see `player.update()`. PyGame groups are designed to let you call `group.update()` in place of a `for x in y` call such as:

```
for sprite in my_sprites:
    sprite.update()
```

EDIT: Not seeing your images in the right place? If they're being set to the upper-left corner, this is usually because nothing is setting the surface of the drawn image to appear where you want it to.

One thing I've found handy about PyGame's `get_rect()` call is that it allows you to pass arguments to set attributes of the `rect` you get back. For example, my `sprite.draw(self)` methods tend to look something like this:

```
def draw(self):
    """Sets the image's Rect to the middle of the sprite, 
    then blits to the screen.
    """
    draw_rect = self.drawn_image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)
    SCREEN.blit(self.drawn_image, draw_rect)
```

This assumes that the sprite object's self.x and self.y are being updated correctly as well, but it's essentially the right thing to do; get the `rect` for the object you're drawing, set it to the right coordinates just as you do the actual sprite, then pass the image and the `rect` to `SCREEN.blit()`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! Ive added the all_sprites call and a few other things. Now the bullet displays once the space bar is pressed however, it just sits in the top left of the screen. Updated code: http://pastebin.com/AgCizAd4

Comment: Typically this is because the `rect` for the image has not been correctly set. I'll update my post

Comment: I tried adding it to the Bullet Sprite, but I have the same outcome. Where would I go about implementing the code youve listed? Sorry if that seems like a silly question

Comment: wherever you draw the sprites - wherever you're using `SCREEN.blit()`. it looks like you're using `self.render()` for this; just set the image's rect before drawing it to match the sprite's rect

Comment: And it's not a silly question - depending on how one prefers to use PyGame, one can see a lot of different answers for how the right way to do things actually is. Some people put all their draw calls in a separate module or class; others use PyGame's native tendency to let sprites do their own updating and drawing etc… I've tried both, they have pros and cons :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback :) Ive added it to both sprites but I get the same outcome :( It must be something I am doing from lack of knowledge

Comment: I still don't see where you're updating ALL the sprites in your code. You're updating player with `player.update()`; you're not updating your all_sprites group though. Instead of player.update() use all_sprites_list.update() and see if it changes anything

Comment: Ah, I did this and now I get a blank screen, the turret doesnt show but when I press space I can see the bullet in the top left of the screen and it looks like its actually firing, before it just appeared and remained stationary... weird. Any idea why this might be?